# JDO integration with hibernate

Tags: java, jpa, jdo

in JPA, to use hibernate, the only thing need to do is moodify persitence.xml and add in hibernate configuration. May i know with JDO, can just by modifying jdoconfig.xml, able to integrate with hibernate? any reference or example on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the reason it works on hibernate+JPA is the JPA specification was developed to be "compatible" with hibernate since hibernate is the dominant persistence API. The tech leads wished that people could move to JPA from hibernate easily.

Furthermore, the JPA specification is not as rigorous or detailed as JDO and thus it is a little more onerous to support JDO (This applies on JPA 1.0, don't know if later versions of JPA bring it more into line with JDO).

The JDO specification was developed independently of hibernate and thus cannot be switched onto JDO.

One obvious difference between hibernate/JPA and JDO is that JDO does not support annotations (it's a pre java 5 specification).

Comment: JDO has supported annotations for 2 years, please check facts. JDO has had 2.1, 2.2 and pre-2.3 specs since then.

Comment: thanks - last I used JDO was version 2.0 and below - glad to know they've added annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore this through ObJectRelationalBridge:

http://db.apache.org/ojb/docu/tutorials/jdo-tutorial.html

Also, I am sure hibernate shall support JDO once JDO gets accepted as the primary way to do things.

JDO is Object Abstraction and it can be supported on any kind of database, however its implementation on Object Data Bases, it is more natural. Google App engine supports JDO since many years.